# error: “store address not aligned on word boundary”

Tags: assembly, mips

When i try to complie my program in MIPS i get this error:

"store address not aligned on word boundary"

Theres my code:

```
.data
string: .asciiz "ola"

a: .ascii "a"
a1: .ascii "ab"

e: .ascii "e"
e1: .ascii "ef"

i: .ascii "i"
i1: .ascii "ij"

o: .ascii "o"
o1: .ascii "op"

u: .ascii "u"
u1: .ascii "uv"

tam: .word 3

.text 

main:
lw $t6, tam #string length
lb $t1, string($t0) #read bit by bit

lh $s0, a #save in register the char that we want to search
lh $s1, a1 #save in register the char that we want to replace


beq $t0, $t6, done

beq $t1, $s0, continua #if the char of (bit by bit) its like the char of chars, swap it
bne $t1, $s0, else #if not, saves
else:
lb $s0, e
lhu $s1, e1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else2

else2:  
lb $s0, i
lh $s1, i1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else3

else3:  
lb $s0, o
lh $s1, o1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, else4                         

else4: 
lb $s0, u
lh $s1, u1

beq $t1, $s0, continua
bne $t1, $s0, store

continua:
la $a0, a
li $v0, 4
syscall
sb $s1, string($t0) #do the swap 
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
j main 

store:
la $a0, a
li $v0, 4
syscall
sh $t1, string($t0) #saves
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #+1 in the index
j main
done:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

The line where i get the error is: "lh $s0, a #save in register the char that we want to search"

Thank you.

Comment: That's unlikely to be the error line. Double check. I would be more worried about the very first instruction `lw $t6, tam` because `tam` might not be aligned (if your assembler doesn't automatically align `.word`).

Comment: what toolchain are you using, gnu doesnt complain. you using spim or something?

Comment: Doesn't work on Mars. See the following error: `Error in line 28: Runtime exception at 0x00400020: fetch address not aligned on halfword boundary 0x10010005`

Comment: Oh yeah characters are 1 byte, better use `lb` not `lh`.

Comment: @Jester oh yea i know.. but i dont want to store one character, i want to store 2 chars at the same time, i tought it would be like that... :/

Comment: @RazvanBalaci did it work after the change? Or you still see issues?

Comment: @RahulBehl after the change it works, but what i want is, after a message for example "hello" it prints "hefllop". With that, it only prints the length of the previous message.